# Distribution of minimum of two uniforms given the maximum

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two random variables uniformly distributed on $(0, 1)$. It is easy to calculate the distribution of minimum and maximum of these two numbers:

$$
P[\max(X_1, X_2)<x] = x^2
$$

$$
P[\min(X_1, X_2)<x] = 1 - P[\min(X_1, X_2)>x] \\
= 1 - (1-x)^2 = 2x-x^2
$$

But what would be the distribution of the minimum, given that the maximum is given and equal to some number $z$, i.e.

$$
P[\min(X_1, X_2)<x | \max(X_1, X_2)=z] = ?
$$

Comment: why is the first result $2x - x^2$? I keep getting $x(1-x)+x(1-x) = 2x - 2x^2$

Comment: @Alex, I added the derivation that I think is correct. In your case, didn't you miss the case that both of the random variables are smaller than $x$?

Comment: OK thanks I got it

Answer (score 2):

Good question, this had me stumped at first.  The minimum is actually the uniform distribution on [0,z].

Without loss of generality, let $X_1$ be at the maximum value z.

Then $P(X_2 > z) = 0$ since z is the max, and $P(X_2 \le z) = 1$.

Let Y be the event that $X_2 \le z$.  Then by Bayes rule.
$$
f_{X_2}(x|Y) = P(Y|X_2=x)f_{X_2}(x)/P(Y) \\
= 0 \quad for \quad x > z \\
= 1(1)/z \quad  for \quad x \le z \\
$$
Therefore the minimum is uniform on [0,z]

Comment: Thanks for that! Does it hold in the more general case where we have $N$ random variables $X_1$, ..., $X_N$, and we condition the distribution of one of them (which is not maximal) on the maximum of all these random variables being $z$?

Comment: New problem $\implies$ New question.